# How do I convert &apos; and %27 to single quote

Tags: java

For example am getting a sting like `&apos; Hello Sir &#39; Hi sir %27 r u der sir`

I need change `&apos;` and `&#39;` and `%27` to single quote.

and able to convert `&#39;` using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(Str)`

is there any function which will do for `&#39;` and `%27` than direct string replace?

Comment: You want to convert html entities in a urlencoded string.

Comment: You've got a string that's a mix of HTML entities and URL encoding?  Yow.

Answer (score 5):

`&#39;` and `&apos;` are XML character entities. You can escape them with [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29).

`%27` is a URL-encoded character. You can escape it with [URLDecoder.decode](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: escapeXml should do that one as well.

Answer (score 2):

- for `%27` you can use `URLDecoder.decode(str)`
- for `&#39;` and `&apos;` you can use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(str)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine using regular expressions.

Without having tested it: (Edit2: Tested it, works!)

```
String str = "&apos; Hello Sir &#39; Hi sir %27 r u der sir";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(&apos;)|(&#39;)|(%27)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
str = m.replaceAll("'");
```

Edit:

Needs

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```